# How to send/receive a chat message using JAXL libraries (XMPP technology, PHP, Openfire server)

Tags: php, xmpp, chat, openfire

I would like to develope a chat using JAXL libraries.

after the connection, i'm using this code to send a message:

```
$client->send_chat_msg('pippo@example.com', 'test');
```

and this code just to show a message has been received.

```
 $client->add_cb('on_chat_message', function() {
    global $client;
    echo "Message received";
    });
```

The problem is:

How can this code works if php is only executed when the page is loaded?

same problem to send messages, how can i send a message without reloading the page?

Any help really appreciated
Thank you
Marco

Comment: Use ajax in the browser to poll PHP for data and to send data.

Comment: i don't think this is a good idea. in this case i would need to use javascript timer and open a new http connection every time i need to update the chat. If this is the solution i could have done the same chat using only php/database and ajax to read/insert data from db. What's the point to install an XMPP server and use XMPP technology then..

Comment: To more easily communicate with an xmpp server

Comment: I think what is more to the point, is that you're trying to solve a problem with the wrong tools.

Comment: can you tell me what tools i have to use then? ;)

Comment: You're just trying to do xmpp in a browser right? If you are, just look for a JavaScript based xmpp library. Also, I didn't mean to sound condescending by saying you're using the wrong tools. Your first instinct of "how can this work?" is pretty much right on.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination.. Yes i need to use just the browser. I've already tried Strophe.js libraries but i was worried that was not the best solution cause you can easily edit username and jid with the browser console and send messages from someone else.. (am i wrong?) So i was looking for some similar libraries in PHP to avoid security problems

Comment: I haven't used Strophe.js, but if you look at http://conversejs.org/ They say it is a full browser chat client with security. I'm assuming Strophe.js has the same ability.

Comment: Thank you, i'm having a look. i will let you know as soon i will try it ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong tool and asking the wrong question.

To run an XMPP client in your user's browser, use Strophe.js or any javascript XMPP client.

JAXL is - when you want to run a client on the server, such as a chatting bot.